# Is $\phi :SL_2(Z) \to SL_2(Z/NZ)$ still surjective if we replace Z with some ring of integers?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms

It is well known that the natural map $\phi :SL_2(Z) \to SL_2(Z/NZ)$ is surjective. So that the kernel, i.e. the principal congruence subgroup is of finite index.

But what if we replace Z with some ring of integers? Is this map still surjective?

Comment: I'm puzzled by your "so that" -- even if it wasn't surjective, its image would still be a subgroup of a finite group and therefore finite, so the kernel would still be of finite index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $SL_2(O_K) \to SL_2(O_K / I)$ is surjective for any ideal $I \triangleleft O_K$, where $K$ is a number field. The "usual" proof for $SL_2(Z)$ works without change for $SL_2(O_K)$ if $O_K$ is Euclidean, see [here](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~ted/620F09/homework/620hw5.pdf). The general case is a little more advanced; there is a very slick proof in these [notes of Brian Conrad](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/248BPage/handouts/strongapprox.pdf) if you're confident working with adeles.

Answer (score 3):

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit and let $I$ be an ideal of $R$.  Then the natural map $SL(n,R) \rightarrow SL(n,R/I)$ is surjective for all $n$, provided $SL(n,R/I)$ is generated by elementary matrices. In particular this is true for $R$ being the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ of a number field $K$.

The question has been discussed in more generality [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78404/when-is-sln-r-rightarrow-sln-r-q-surjective). In fact, there are rings $R$ such that the above map is *not* surjective, e.g., for $R=\mathbb{Z}[a,b,c,d]$ and ideal $I$ generated by $ad-bc-1$.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question since $N$ need not generate a maximal ideal

Comment: @hunter Now it does (before I though the OP was satisfied with maximal ideals; also not every ring of integers is a PID, so anyway one has to discuss what ideal).